# What is a practical example using distantFuture?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, foundation

DispatchTime and (NS)Date have the property [`distantFuture`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchtime/1780795-distantfuture), which "returns a time in the distant future."

> #### Discussion:
>
> You can pass this value to methods that schedule work to have the system wait indefinitely for a particular event to occur or condition to be met.

I can't think of or find an example where I would actually need to use this. What is a good use case?

Comment: Why not [search on distanceFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+distantFuture) to find examples? [Searching on distantPast](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+distantPast) helps too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144424/1226963 for a recent example using `distantPast`.

Comment: @rmaddy I did search and just wasn't satisfied with what I found. I haven't ever needed to make a synchronous HTTP request for instance (thought to be fair that question has been viewed 16913 times!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For example if you want to retrieve future events from a calendar with an unspecified end date.

In this case you can set the end date of the predicate to `distantFuture`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an **example** what unspecific dates will be returned:

```swift
let date = Date()
// current, here: "Sep 30, 2020 at 9:27 AM"

let distantPast = Date.distantPast
// "Jan 1, 1 at 12:53 AM"

let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture
// "Jan 1, 4001 at 1:00 AM"
```