# Core Data extension to sort entities

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, entity

The bottom line is to write an extension that sorts an array of `NSManagedObjects` by `dateCreated`. Or, to go from this:

```
let materialArray = (Array(quote.materials!) as? [Materials])?.sorted(by: { $0.dateCreated?.compare($1.dateCreated!) == .orderedDescending })
```

to this:

```
let materialArray = (Array(quote.materials!) as? [Materials])?.sortedByDate
```

All of my entities inherit a created date, including the one above called `Materials`. I'd like to write an extension to sort by that date but I'm not sure what to extend...or how. So far I have:

```
extension Materials
{
    func sortedByDate() -> [Materials]
    {
        return self.sorted(by: { $0.dateCreated?.compare($1.dateCreated!) == .orderedDescending })
    }
}
```

The biggest problem is the error stating that `Materials` has no member '`sorted`'. Making this extension work with all entities that inherit `dateCreated` is the ultimate goal. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you'll need to define the method for an *array* of Materials, not for a (single) Material object. – Have a look at [Generic function to sort array of class by properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599074/generic-function-to-sort-array-of-class-by-properties)  for some generic solutions.

Comment: Needing an array type should have been obvious since I am trying to sort one. As for generics, I guess I've been putting off learning about them long enough...