# Sort dictionary by keys in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `[Int : String]` that I want to sort by the keys and then convert it into array. For example:

```
let dict : [Int : String] = [18 : "Maya", 13 : "Ori", 49 : "Mom", 21 : "Lital", 51 : "Dad"]
// After convertion:
// ["Ori", "Maya", "Lital", "Mom", "Dad"]
```

How do I do that?
I only know how to convert `dict` into array by doing `Array(dict.values)`, but it doesn't make that in the right order.

**Thanks**

Comment: `let sortedValuesByKeys = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }).map { $0.1 }` should do the trick. Since Dictionaries aren't ordered, we sort a tuple (key, value), that we sort, then get (map) only the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dictionary` already has a `sorted` method that takes a closure that defines the sorting function. You can sort by keys in the closure, then simply map over the resulting tuples to get the values only.

```
let sortedDictKeys = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }).map(\.value)
```

Comment: You can use keypath when mapping the values `map(\.1)` or for batter readability `map(\.value)`

Comment: @LeoDabus `.map(\.value)` does read better, updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: To sort a dictionary using its keypath you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63018749/2303865) `dict.sorted(\.key).map(\.value)` or `dict.sorted(\.key, by: >).map(\.value)`

Answer (score 1):

**I have converted in the following way:-**

```
 let dict : [Int : String] = [18 : "Maya", 13 : "Ori", 49 : "Mom", 21 : "Lital", 51 : "Dad"]
 let sortedDict = dict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
 let sortedDictArray = Array(sortedDict.map({ $0.value }))
 print(sortedDictArray)
```

**The output is:-**

```
 ["Ori", "Maya", "Lital", "Mom", "Dad"]
```

Comment: Initilizing an array is pointless. map already returns an array.