# What is the correct Array Sort syntax?

Tags: swift, sorting

**Goal:** to sort an array of structs per struct.state field.

**Current Scenario:** Data isn't sorted alphabetically per state.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
struct RevisedNigeriaDataListElement: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID
    let state: String
    let cases, active, recovered, deaths: String
}

typealias RevisedNigeriaDataList = [RevisedNigeriaDataListElement]



  func processData(origData: NigeriaDataList) {
        var data: RevisedNigeriaDataList = []

        for item in origData {
            let element = RevisedNigeriaDataListElement(
                id: UUID(),
                state: item.state,
                cases: item.cases.str,
                active: item.active.str,
                recovered: item.recovered.str,
                deaths: item.deaths.str
            )

            data.append(element)
        }
    
        revisedData = data.sorted(by: { $0.state: String, $1.state: String in
            $0 < $1
        })
    }
```

**My problem**: is the 'data.sorted'.

[image]

Each member of the data struct is a String.  
What is the correct syntax?

Comment: you might be interested in sorting a collection using a KeyPath. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63018749/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$0` and `$1` are [Shorthand Argument Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID100). The correct syntax is this:

```
data.sorted(by: { $0.state < $1.state })
```

Alternatively, you can forgo the shorthand arguments and define them yourself:

```
data.sorted(by: { firstElement, secondElement in
    firstElement.state < secondElement.state
})
```

Note that you don't put `: String`. You are calling the `sorted` method on an array of `RevisedNigeriaDataList`, so the type is inferred.